# Pressure increasing with depth work for directions other than downward

Tags: forces, buoyancy

How does pressure increasing with depth work for directions other than downward? Can you explain this on the macro and micro level?

I get how it works on a macro level for downward forces because there is more mass when you go downward and given that $F=ma$ and $P=\frac{F}{A}$. 
But how do you explain it on a micro level?
Or even on a macro level for say upward or left/rightward forces(as shown in the picture below)?

[image]
￼

Answer (score 0):

In a macro level, an object at some depth experiences a force in all directions.

What you should understand is the fact that the components of  all the forces acting to the left and right cancels out because if I consider a thin cross section of the object at any height, the pressure from all the directions is the same so it all cancels out.

If I consider the top and bottom of the object,

$P_{top}= \rho g x_{top}$

$P_{bottom}= \rho g x_{bottom}$

$P_{bottom}= \rho g (x_{top}+h_{object})$

As you can clearly see that there is a pressure difference in the top and bottom of the object( the lowermost point is at higher pressure).

This pressure difference causes a net upward force.